# Truncate table with ActiveJDBC

Tags: activejdbc

What is the best way to truncate a table with ActiveJDBC? The Model class only has deleteAll().
So I guess I need to run a native SQL query, is `Base.exec("TRUNCATE TABLE table1")` the way to go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to execute arbitrary SQL, use Base.exec(sql).